# Optimizing Using String Arrays in Timer Loops in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

**Preface**
I am using Visual Studio Community 2022. I'm trying to make a simple c# windows form app to learn c#. I'm not unfamiliar with coding logic, but I am a c# newbie. This is my first question here.

**What I am doing**
There are several textboxes in the form, I am getting the string contents of those textboxes into a string array. Then a button enables a timer that uses that array among other things. Currently, since I couldn't find a better way to do it, this is the way it works (and it does work):

```
private string[] xxx()
{
    string[] yyy = { textbox1.Text, textbox2.Text, etc. };
    return yyy;
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] zzz = xxx();
    // use zzz below
}
```

The textboxes can't be edited when the timer is enabled, so the yyy array can't change during that time (I disable the textboxes once the timer starts - until it stops). I don't know if it's the best way to do it, but something feels odd to use another function repeatedly in the Timer, instead of a simple array variable that's defined once and used in the Timer. Is this code optimized enough or is there a better way to do it?

**Edit:** From the first few comments it seems what I was trying to do is unclear. I **assume** the code is unoptimized because it gets the values from the textboxes each time the timer ticks. So what I'm trying to do (or rather what I **think** would be more optimized) is getting the values from the textboxes to an array once, and use that array in the timer. So in short:

Instead of this:

- timer ticks: get all the values from the textboxes onto an array -
  use that array
- timer ticks: get all the values from the textboxes onto an array -
  use that array
- timer ticks: get all the values from the textboxes onto an array -
  use that array

I'm trying to do this:

- get all the values from the textboxes onto an array
- timer ticks: use array
- timer ticks: use array
- timer ticks: use array

Comment: "simple array variable that's defined once and used in the Timer" I don't see a problem just doing so.

Comment: The question is unclear. First of all, your code isn't modifying the textboxes, it's reading from them. There's no need for `xxx()`. You can't modify any UI element from a background thread, and using another method doesn't change that. If you used `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, the event would be processed by the UI thread so you'd still be able to modify the textboxes.

Comment: @Ralf the problem is that even if by `variable` you mean `field`, the strings in it won't change when the textboxes change.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos he states that he don't want that to change while the timer is enabled.

Comment: You're trying to *do something* and you came up with a solution. I'd suggest you explain what that *something* is instead of asking to fix code that is not exactly clear what is meant to really accomplish. I.e., talk about the problem itself, not about a problem caused by the current attempt to solve the actual problem

Comment: @Ralf First of all, the contents won't change because the Timer.Tick event is running on the UI thread. It makes sense to store the field contents in variables if they're reused though, just to clean up the code and extract some of it into other methods. The variable contents wouldn't change even if `Application.DoEvents()` was called to allow the UI to refresh or change

Comment: From the first few comments it seems what I was trying to do is unclear. I **assume** the code is unoptimized because it gets the values from the textboxes each time the timer ticks. So in short:

Instead of this:
timer ticks - get all the values from the textboxes onto an array - use that array
timer ticks - get all the values from the textboxes onto an array - use that array

I'm trying to do this:
get all the values from the textboxes onto an array
timer ticks - use array
timer ticks - use array

Comment: That does still not explain the actual purpose of the code. Are you doing some kind of slow computation? Some kind of continuous simulation? Why isn't the user allowed to change the textboxes while timer is running? And you should be *very* careful with making assumptions about performance, *especially* as a new developer. Instead learn how to *measure* performance. See Stopwatch class, Benchmark.Net & Visual studio performance profiler for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting the TextBox's Text into an array, you can put the TextBoxes themselves into the array. Since TextBoxes are classes and therefore reference types, this array will store the references to these TextBoxes and you will be able to retrieve (or set) the actual Text values.

```cs
private TextBox[] _textBoxes;

// Form Constructor
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _textBoxes = new[] { textbox1, textbox2, etc. };

    // Or, starting with C# 12
    _textBoxes = [ textbox1, textbox2, etc. ];
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Use _textBoxes[i].Text;
}
```

Note that you must initialize the array **after** `InitializeComponent` has been called, since this is the method which creates the controls of the Form.